# Case-insensitive sort ordering in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Consider the following criteria query:

var x = SomeCriteria.AddOrder(new Order("Name", true)).List();

This will order the result set by the Name property, but case sensitive:

```
"A1"
"B1"
"a2"
```

Any ideas how to add the order case insensitive so result "a2" will end up before "B1"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by ordering on a projection that normalizes the case for you. For example, Oracle has a "lower" function that will lower case string data types like varchar2 and nvarchar2; so I will use this sql function to form a projection that will order appropriately.

```
var projection = Projections.SqlFunction("lower", 
                                         NHibernateUtil.String, 
                                         Projections.Property("Name"));

var x = SomeCriteria.AddOrder(Orders.Asc(projection)).List()
```

If you're using SQL Server, I'd recommend using the "upper" function instead of "lower" for efficiency.  Microsoft has optimized its native code for performing uppercase comparisons, where the rest of the world seems to have optimized on lowercase.

Comment: This is awesome. However when I'm doing sorting in a grid, I don't know the column type. Do you know if I can somehow detect the column type and only apply this projection to strings?

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate (Java) has an "ignoreCase()" method on the "Order" class, but it looks like NHibernate does not have this method on its "Order."

This is how I was thinking you could do it:

```
var x = SomeCriteria.AddOrder(new Order("Name", true).IgnoreCase()).List();
```

But unfortunately, there is no IgnoreCase().

As a workaround, you could use an HQL or SQL query - either of those should allow you to order case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

This probably depends on a case-sensitivity setting on your database server. I suspect that NHibernate just issues an "ORDER BY" clause; at least, I can't imagine what else it would do. For SQL Server, the default sort order (collation) is dictionary order, case insensitive.

[This article](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm) gives some techniques for performing case sensitive searches in SQL Server. However, my advice is to sort the list that is returned by the query in code. That solution preserves the database independence of NHibernate and let's you customize the sort order per your needs.

Comment: -1 Are you seriously suggesting to skip optimized db sort and use sorting in your code? Have you tested such solution in production system for performance?

Comment: Yes and yes. Have you? Without more specifics in the original question (RDBMS in use, number of rows expected) it's impossible to weigh the advantage of sorting in code (flexible, dynamic, database independent) vs. sorting on the server. Database independence is a primary reason for using an O/R mapper and usually worth preserving in an application.

Answer (score 0):

As I know the responses to my query are always fairly small, I ended up querying the data as normal and sorting them afterwards using Linq. It works, so why bother tweaking NHibernate ;) (Using SQLite, btw)